# convert list variable name as key and its value as value of dictionary in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, type-conversion

I have a Python list like:

```
lst = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

I want a `dictionary` with `key` as `lst` and `value` as a,b,c,d.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: ```dictionary = {'lst': lst}```?

Answer (score 1):

Here is how:

```
lst = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
dct = {'lst': lst}

print(dct)
```

Output:

```
{'lst': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']}
```

---

But if the value you're expecting is really `a,b,c,d`, you'll need to use the `str.join()` method on the list:

```
lst = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
dct = {'lst': ','.join(lst)}

print(dct)
```

Output:

```
{'lst': 'a,b,c,d'}
```